# Configuring RAID1 on HP Proliant Microserver N54L / Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hp, hp-proliant, software-raid

I've bought a N54L and fitted two 3GB drives. Keen to get set up with RAID1.

- BIOS: SATA controller mode set to "RAID"
- RAID Option ROM utility: both physical drives set up as one logical drive

When I came to install Ubuntu (14.04.1), both drives appeared during the setup process. I was only expecting to see the logical drive, although I'm a complete novice with RAID.

I've read that the HP Proliant Microservers don't have "proper" RAID support, and require some kind of driver to be installed. I've tried a few HP utilities from the following apt repo:

```
deb http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/repo/mcp wheezy/current non-free
```

On installation, most say "server not supported"

Would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of similar questions in a short period...

Ubuntu isn't well-suited to vendor-specific hardware support (*probably the vendors' fault, but it is what it is*). The HP ProLiant N54L server you have has binary drivers for the storage array that are [only available for Windows and Red Hat](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5336626&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3DswEnvOID%253D4004%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#Driver%20-%20Storage).

See: [Cant find my harddrives in ubuntu installation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/620692/cant-find-my-harddrives-in-ubuntu-installation/620695#620695)

The RAID controller in this particular Microserver is a fakeraid controller. You're better off using software RAID or fitting an HP Smart Array p410 controller into the server for proper hardware RAID.